# Small DB table (Oracle) still huge execution time for SELECT * FROM

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I have a quite small table in `Oracle 12c`. It has around 45K records and size is 12MB (after recent gather stats). But it takes 30 sec to 1 min 30 secs to run

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Additionally if I run

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 123
```

(where id is an indexed column) it too takes around 45 secs.

What could be wrong?

UPDATE:
Explain plan as requested.

```
SELECT * FROM {table_name}

SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 410  Bytes: 14,733,600  Cardinality: 43,850      
    1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE {table_name} Cost: 410  Bytes: 14,733,600  Cardinality: 43,850  


SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE id = 123

SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 2  Bytes: 672  Cardinality: 2          
    2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED TABLE {table_name} Cost: 2  Bytes: 672  Cardinality: 2      
        1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX {index_name} Cost: 1  Cardinality: 2
```

Sorry for hiding the object name to comply with organization policy

Comment: There could be a lot wrong. I found a post with listed tools which might help you to check what is happening. (https://community.oracle.com/thread/503834) Have you already tried some of them, and if yes what were the output?

Comment: Does it happen only on this table or also in other tables (in the same database or even on other database)? It's may lead you to where you need to look at (table, database or server configuration).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)  not as a screenshot

Comment: Are there many other columns in your table?. Does the table have clob/blob datatypes which are being retreived when doing SELECT *

How much time does the following query take

SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 123

Comment: Does the disk the table is located have too much I/O

Comment: I have shared the plan as requested

it's happening only on this table. The table has one big trigger but that should impact only write operations. Isn't it ?

There are just 12 columns and no BLOB/CLOB datatype

Comment: There's nothing wrong indicated by those query plans. Low cardinality, low data volume, efficient use of index where possible. So the poor performance must be due to some other factor(s) (e.g. disk issues, network issues, OS issues, client issues). I would see if I can connect directly to the database server and run the query locally to see if I could eliminate some of these factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After liaising with DBA, we found above query was mostly waiting on library cache lock and library cache pin wait events. The table had more than one hundred thousand views (with dynamic names like VW_TABLE_12345, VW_TABLE_12346 etc.) created on it as dependent objects which was apparently a very bad design. When we changed code and cleared all the views, the table was as fast as it should be

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things can be wrong but two come to mind.

First is that your query with `WHERE ID = 123` is returning a significant number of rows.  Beyond a certain threshold, the database will decide that a full table scan is more efficient than using the index.  This is related to the idea of *cardinality* of the values in the index.

Second, is that `ID` is not a number.  If it is a string, then the column is being converted to a number and that could preclude the use of an index.

There are other possibilities, but these seem like the most likely.